# Find first matching substring in a long string in R

Tags: r, regex, string

I'm trying to find the first matching string from a vector in a long string. I have for example a `example_string <- 'LionabcdBear1231DogextKittyisananimalTurtleisslow'` and a `matching_vector<- c('Turtle',Dog')` Now I want that it returns 'Dog' as this is the first substring in the matching_vector that we see in the example string:  LionabcdBear1231**Dog**extKittyisananimalTurtleisslow

I already tried `pmatch(example_string,matching_vector)` but it doesn't work. Obviously as it doesn't work with substrings...

Thanks!
Tim

Comment: Try `library(stringi);stri_match_first(example_string, regex = paste(matching_vector, collapse="|"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `stri_match_first` from `stringi`

```
library(stringi)
stri_match_first(example_string, regex = paste(matching_vector, collapse="|"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Is the following solution working for you?

```
example_string <- 'LionabcdBear1231DogextKittyisananimalTurtleisslow'
matching_vector<- c('Turtle','Dog')
match_ids <- sapply(matching_vector, function(x) regexpr(x ,example_string)) 
result <- names(match_ids)[which.min(match_ids)]
> result
[1] "Dog"
```